# FreeRadius + PHP Configuration

Tags: php, radius, freeradius

I'm trying to configure FreeRadius to authenticate using a PHP script. I've been messing around trying to get it to get the server to authenticate based on the script, but I can't find much documentation on doing it that way.

This is what we're trying to configure.

We have a web server, that has a Wordpress site installed on it with thousands of users. We're wanting to install a WiFi service at certain locations that uses FreeRadius for authentication and we want it to allow users that are signed up on the Wordpress site to use their credentials.

The problem I'm facing right now is that I can't seem to get FreeRadius to authenticate based on the PHP script.

This is what I've configured thus far based on other StackOverflow posts have mentioned with their configuration.

I've created the following file in `/etc/modules/php` and added this

```
exec php {
    wait = yes
    program = "/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/myscript.php"
    input_pairs = request
    output_pairs = reply
}
```

In `/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default` I've added the following:

```
authenticate {
  Auth-Type PHP {
    php
  }
}
```

In `/etc/raddb/users` I've added the following line to the end

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := PHP
```

In terms of the `myscript.php` file, I've added responses just to see what I could get and printed "Access-Accept" or "Access-Reject" to see if it would give me any clues whether it would authenticate based on those responses, but neither helped.

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I've tried the method listed here: [Freeradius and PHP auth script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542268/freeradius-and-php-auth-script) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in your link  for updating control:Auth-Type should work. Make sure it's done in `authorize {}`

Change your responses to `Accept` and `Reject` (as per the link you posted). `Access-Accept` != `Accept`, `Access-Reject` != `Reject`.

For clarity and to avoid annoying log message add:

```
authenticate {
    reject
}
```

Which will add an `Auth-Type reject { reject }` section.

You don't need to do anything for `Accept`, as there's a builtin auth type `Accept` that causes authentication to always succeed.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Basically just printing "Accept" or "Reject" in the PHP script returns the correct value.