# Freeradius and external script authentication with CHAP / MS-CHAP

Tags: php, authentication, freeradius

I am using Freeradius to authenticate users via an external script as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542268/freeradius-and-php-auth-script), that returns Accept or Reject when passed a username and password pair.

```
authorize{
    update control { 
        Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/yourscript.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'`
    }
```

This works properly as expected when the client is using PAP. The password is sent in `%{User-Password}`.

However when using CHAP or MS-CHAP it does not work, as `%{User-Password}` remains empty.

How can I get the plaintext password to send to my script? Alternatively, is there any other way to support CHAP/MS-CHAP?

Answer (score 1):

The `%{CHAP-Password}` field contains a hash of the password and the challenge, which is some magic number.

The `%{CHAP-Challenge}` field contains the challenge used in that session.

While you can't get the plain-text password from this in a straightforward realtime way, if you have the plaintext password you can hash it with the CHAP-Challenge as shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/radius.constants.attributes.php) using md5. This should then be equal to your CHAP-Password value.

Comment: Could you please add code to what i have to do 
      Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/yourscript.php '%{User-Name}' '%{CHAP-Password}'` is this will send the pasword ??